# How can submit my paper to Elsevier when not affiliated?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I have obtained my master a couple years ago and am looking into pursuing a PhD. I currently have a part time job completely irrelevant to academia. For applying for a PhD, I figured that I need a research paper, I haven't been totally disconnected from learning in this period and have recently written a paper with a faculty member with me doing all the major part and her evaluating/reviewing. When trying to submit the manuscript to Elsevier, the very first thing I'm required to fill in as the correspondence author is my affiliation, It won't even go to the next step :( I really want to submit my paper to this particular journal. I don't know what to do, should I call the Elsevier offices? would that make a difference? Are there recent corresponding authors in Elsevier with no affiliation. Please let me know anything that might be helpful. I would greatly appreciate it. :)

Comment: I'll give it a try, the thing is that if I write "Independent Scholar", It says organization not found, and ask for details (address etc.) Can I enter the university address of my coauthor and write independent scholar?

Comment: If you aren't affiliated don't do that. Try "independent researcher", or "unaffiliated" or "none". If they all fail, ask Elsevier. But it is common enough that they will have a solution.

Comment: Good to know! Thank you :))

Comment: Also the fact of having a coauthor who has affiliation should help. Talk to him/her and the university even before contacting Elsevier.